# ASP.net master page/content page simple design problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, public, content-pages

My master page:

```
public partial class MasterPages_Main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public bool IsLoggedIn;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Check login
        LoggedInUser ThisUser = new LoggedInUser();
        IsLoggedIn = ThisUser.IsLoggedIn;

        Response.Write("Master" + IsLoggedIn.ToString());

    }
```

This outputs 'True', we are logged in.

On my content page I do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Write("CONTENT:" + Master.IsLoggedIn.ToString());
}
```

But this outputs 'False'.

So the actual page output is:

```
Content:False
Master:True
```

On my content page I need to redirect if the user is logged in, but this value is always false from the content pages point of view!  How can I resolve this?

Comment: Solved, changing master to page_init works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content Page load event occurs before Master Load (from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx)). So you probably need to change the logic, and maybe call some content page's methods from master `Page_Load`. Or set `IsLoggedIn` inside Master Init event handler.

Comment: Thanks, init didn't work as it did the same things for some other logic, but modularising it and putting some logic inside master functions seems to have resolved this.

Answer (score 2):

Change Master `Page_Load` to `Page_Init`, this will force it to execute before the content page.

Answer (score 1):

The master page is called after your code for Page_Load().  Try this:

```
Protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.Page_Load(sender,e); 
    Response.Write("CONTENT:" + Master.IsLoggedIn.ToString());
}
```

Comment: If it's never called then how is it currently outputting `Master:True`?

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work.  Also I think it is loading, because it's getting everything fine, but it's just loading in the wrong order

Comment: Changing the master page_load to page_init seems to force it to load first which works.

Comment: see above for correct code.  The default case is that base.Page_Load is called after your inherited Page_Load() -- the code above will fix this.

Comment: Yes, Page_Init is called before Page_Load in the Page Life Cycle.